# Modify Eye-of-Gnome (EoG) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, eog

tl;dr version:

How should I modify the keyboard shortcuts of `Eye-of-Gnome (EoG)`

===============

More info:

As noted [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/eog/issues/6), `Spacebar` will not be supported as a shortcut for viewing the next image.

So I want to edit the keyboard shortcuts for `EoG`. Based on instructions on this [unix.stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177271/eye-of-gnome-eog-modify-shortcuts) I tried editing the `~/.config/eog/accels`

I got a sample `accels` file from [github](https://github.com/foozlevazquez/iv-linux-dot-config/blob/master/eog/accels).

I tried un-commenting and modifying appropriate lines. It makes no difference to `EoG` shortcuts.

This problem of `EoG` not responding to changes in `accels` file is also reported in this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/9wjtbv/problem_with_modifying_shortcuts_in_eye_of_gnome/) post, but isn't resolved and the thread is archived.

===============

**EDIT:** I am also open to a "hacky" solution involving modifying source code and compiling. As `EoG` is a huge project, I need help in identifying the region of the project that needs to be modified.

Comment: I am using: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: Unfortunately, modern Gnome applications do not allow to customize keybindings anymore. The mechanism with the accels file is not more applicable.

Comment: Yes that is really unfortunate then. :/

Comment: Is there a hacky way of doing this then - such as downloading source, modifying source and compiling? I would like to be pointed to instructions on how to do this.

Comment: For sure, you can edit and recompile the source code. If you are interested in such approach, mention this in your question to eventually attract answers in that direction.

Comment: Editing source, recompile would be undone on each and every update. ^

Comment: Alright, how do I close this question? I have given up on EoG by now and it is much easier to use another image viewer (I recommend feh or vimiv). Or should I delete the question?